# In PowerShell, is it fine to modify a hashtable when iterating over it?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

This is the code:

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | %{
    if($_.value.x -eq $null)
    {
        $hash.remove($_.name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it modifies the hashtable when iterating over it. Is this fine?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this on PowerShell 2.0:

```
$hash = @{"A1"="rouge";"A2"="vert";"A3"="bleu"}
$hash.GetEnumerator() | % { if($_.value -eq "bleu") {$hash.remove($_.name)}}
```

It gives :

```
Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'énumération parmi une collection : La collection a été modifiée ; l'opération d'énumérat
ion peut ne pas s'exécuter..
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 1
+  <<<< $hash.GetEnumerator() | % { if($_.value -eq "bleu") {$hash.remove($_.name)}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...tableEnumerator:HashtableEnumerator) [], RuntimeExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

The reason is that trying to modify the collection while enumerating through it, throw an exception. You can try using "for" statement.

If you want to use `foreach` statement you can try :

```
$hash = @{"A1"="rouge";"A2"="vert";"A3"="bleu"}
[string[]]$t = $hash.Keys
$t |  % { if($hash[$_] -eq "vert") {$hash.remove($_)}}
$hash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
A3                             bleu
A1                             rouge
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\> $h = @{ "a"=1; "b"=2; "c"=3; "d"=4 }
PS C:\> $h.GetEnumerator() | % {
>> if ($_.Value -eq 2) { $h.Remove($_.Name) }
>> "{0}: {1}" -f $_.Name, $_.Value
>> }
>>
a: 1
b: 2
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Collection was
modified; enumeration operation may not execute..
At line:1 char:1
+  <<<< $h.getenumerator() | % {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
      (System.Collecti...tableEnumerator:HashtableEnumerator) [],
      RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

Is it really that hard to run a simple test before posting a question?